# Python xlsxwriter loop through each worksheet in a workbook

Tags: python, for-loop, xlsxwriter

I want to iterate through each worksheet that I have created in a workbook with add_worksheet function.
I want to do this with all the available sheets in the workbook and write 'Hello' in cell 'A1' of each sheet.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx',{'nan_inf_to_errors': True})
WS1 = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet A')
WS2 = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet B')
WS2 = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet C')

for WS in enumerate(workbook.worksheets):
    WS.write('A1','Hello!')

workbook.close()
```

I was expecting it to write 'Hello' in cell 'A1' for each available sheet in the workbook.

Getting this error : TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and add parenthesis to [`workbook.worksheets`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html).

Try this :

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx', {'nan_inf_to_errors': True})

WS1 = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet A')
WS2 = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet B')
WS2 = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet C')

for WS in workbook.worksheets():
    WS.write('A1','Hello!')

workbook.close()
```